# Passing arguments to the Class Constructor

Tags: php, class, object

How can I pass a arbitrary number of arguments to the class constructor using the Object() function defined below?

```
<?php

/*
./index.php
*/

function Object($object)
{
    static $instance = array();

    if (is_file('./' . $object . '.php') === true)
    {
        $class = basename($object);

        if (array_key_exists($class, $instance) === false)
        {
            if (class_exists($class, false) === false)
            {
                require('./' . $object . '.php');
            }

            /*
            How can I pass custom arguments, using the
            func_get_args() function to the class constructor?

            $instance[$class] = new $class(func_get_arg(1), func_get_arg(2), ...);
            */

            $instance[$class] = new $class();
        }

        return $instance[$class];
    }

    return false;
}

/*
How do I make this work?
*/

Object('libraries/DB', 'DATABASE', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')->Query(/* Some Query */);

/*
./libraries/DB.php
*/

class DB
{
    public function __construct($database, $username, $password, $host = 'localhost', $port = 3306)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$klass = new ReflectionClass($classname);
$thing = $klass->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

Although the need to use reflection suggests that you are overcomplicating something in your design. Why do you want to write this function in the first place?

Comment: I admit this function may seem a bit nonsense but I use it for small stuff where a framework may be too bloated. And since it acts as an "autoloader", object constructor and singleton container it does the job perfectly.

Comment: BTW, that Reflection class is really handy, is there any crash course available on the new features of PHP 5.3? I checked the PHP manual but is it me or it is lacking a lot of documentation?

Comment: It's not you: The documentation is rather sparse on that. You'll have to do with http://www.php.net/oop5.reflection. Also, it has been around since 5.1 (or is it 5.0?), so it's not a new feature of 5.3

Answer (score 3):

Instead of your class taking separated parameters I'd have it take an array.

```
class DB
{
    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

That way you can pass the direct result of the func_get_args into your constructor. The only problem now is being able to figure out the array key / values.

If anyone else has any ideas I'd also be delighted to know :)

Comment: I got the same idea as well but I was curious to know if something like I described could be done.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but `call_user_func_array` sounds like you want.

```
$thing = call_user_func_array(array($classname, '__construct'), $args);
```

Have a look in the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Comment: Doesn't work. =\

call_user_func_array(array(new $classname(), '__construct'), $args);

This works but then I would be calling the constructor twice.

Comment: Try it without new $classname().

Comment: Fatal error: Non-static method test::__construct() cannot be called statically

Comment: Okay, I've got no more ideas. Thanks for being willing to try.

Comment: if you doing this in a dynamic way use type hints for your arguments in the class constructor

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for the reflection method, would be evaluate your code.

```
eval('$instance = new className('.implode(', ', $args).');');
```

Comment: Eval is pretty much always a bad idea